# How do I divide a Numpy array along axis-0 into a list of equal sized numpy arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

For example array

```
x = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
```

Divided into 4 "folds" along axis-0 would be like a list

```
[array([1]), array([2]), array([3]), array([4])]
```

Clearly, for this to be achieved some data has to be removed. In this case the 5th and 6th element are. How can I split any array into equally-sized sub-arrays EVEN if they are not easily divisible by the number of sub-arrays necessary and data must be removed?

Answer (score 2):

It is straightforward, as you said, to trim the array before partitioning:

```
n = 4
x[:len(x)//n*n].reshape(n,-1)
```

Output:

```
array([[1],
       [2],
       [3],
       [4]])
```

Comment: Hello, Quang thank you for your answer. I have an additional question. I need the result to be [array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])], but using your method it is [array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]])]. How do I get a result with shape [6, ] instead of [1, 6].

Comment: @NicholasFowlkes. You want 6, 1

Answer (score 1):

Use [`np.split`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.split.html) and modulo to carefully trim your array ahead of time:

```
N = 4
x = np.arange(6)
trim = len(x) % N or None
result = np.split(x[:trim], N)
```

If `len(x)` is not a multiple of `N`, `trim` will be the correct amount. If it is, the modulo will be zero and `or None` will take care of the subsequent slice.